# Is the Gouvea-Mazur problem related to symmetric square $L$-functions?

Tags: modular-forms, rigid-analytic-geometry, l-functions

Here's an idea that I've found appealing but have never been able to get anywhere with.

One way to frame the Gouvea-Mazur question (for lack of a better term, since the original conjecture by the same name has been disproven) is as follows:  Let $\pi:\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{W}$ be the eigencurve (of some tame level) with its natural projection to weight space.  Given a classical point $x\in \mathcal{E}$, what is the radius of the largest disk around $\pi(x)\in \mathcal{W}$ over which $\pi$ admits a section sending $\pi(x)$ to $x$?

Ramification points of the map $\pi$ provide natural obstructions to the existence of such a section.  On the other hand, these ramification points arise naturally as the zeros of a symmetric square $L$-function on $\mathcal{E}$.  This is the the main result of Walter Kim's 2006 thesis written under Robert Coleman (which, as far as I know, never appeared anywhere).

I once had a chat with Barry Mazur in which he (very roughly - these are my words from my recollection several years on) said that this symmetric square $L$ function should be thought of as a section of $\Omega^1_{\mathcal{E}}$, namely the pullback of the differential $dt/t$ on $\mathcal{W}$ via $\pi$.  (Here $t$ is the coordinate on the disk of radius $1$ about $1 \in \mathbb{C}_p$ and we're using the usual identification of $\mathcal{W}$ with a stack of such disks.)

Clearly $\omega=\pi^*(dt/t)$ has zeros precisely at the ramification points.  More generally:

> 1) Is the "size" of $\omega$ related to the maximal radius of a section to $\pi$?
>
> 2) Is this radius then related to the algebraic part of the symmetric square $L$-function?

The first question isn't so well-posed, and may rely on an integral model (formal scheme) giving rise to $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: "should be thought of as a section" - is some version of this literally true?

Comment: @David: I don't know, but the fact that their zeros coincide is somehow compelling.  My recollection is that Mazur was musing about "where $L$-values naturally lie" as objects on the eigencurve, and that, in the case of the symmetric square $L$-function, the answer seems to be $\Omega^1$.

Comment: This really confuses me. If you consider some $p$-adic symmetric square $L$-function then its value is a $p$-adic number, so how can it be considered as a differential? I had always thought that (special values of) $p$-adic $L$-functions were just going to be meromorphic functions on the eigencurve.

Comment: To employ a potentially dangerous analogy - a cusp form $f$ of weight two is just a function and it's values are just complex numbers.  Nonetheless, there is good reason for thinking of such a thing as a differential form (in this because of the functional equations satisfied by $f$).  It wouldn't surprise me if there was something much deeper behind Mazur's comment, but what I took from the conversation was:  since the zeros of $L(Sym^2)$ are exactly the zeros of $\omega$, does this mean that there is some natural sense in which these two objects coincide?

Comment: @Ramsey: I don't buy it! A cusp form of weight 2 is a function on the *upper half plane*, *not* a function on a modular curve. The sheaf of differentials on the upper half plane is canonically trivial; the sheaf of differentials on a modular curve is not. So from that optic it's not surprising at all that a weight 2 modular form is a function---it's just not a function on the right space :-) 

Comment: @Kevin: Well, I'm not selling it very well. Probably because I don't understand it!  Beyond the zeros issue, I have no motivation for (2).  The point (1) is unrelated, and I'd be mighty curious if some version of it were true in general.  It is easy to write down toy examples of ramified maps where something like (1) is evident, but I don't have general statement or argument.